# How to split cable? (5V 5A Power Supply)

Tags: power, current, split

I have a 5V 5A DC power supply. From this power-supply I want to power 6 seperate 5V devices, which aren't connected in any way except the common power-line. My understanding is that I simply can divide the cables. Is there any hardware for doing so ("split clamps" or something like that)? How would you do it? I don't have that much space - so a small solution would be great.

Comment: Splice the cable, use terminal connectors a terminal block or how ever else you would connect 7 conductors.

Comment: Are you familiar with parallel / in series connections? You may want to google that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of clamps out there to split wires. I've seen twist-on clamps (but never used them), "wago" clamps, distribution strips, etc. There is also solder, but solder is often discouraged to use in cable-to-cable connections, as it causes a point of stress. General splicing is to my knowledge better.

Ofcourse, I hope it is evident that you need to put the 6 devices in parallel, not in series. If this is not obvious, perhaps it's worth taking a step back and looking up some basic material on series/parallel and Ohm's law before you start.

Without more information, it's hard to provide a more specifict solution.